# WPF binding to ComboBox within Popup control using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am having an issue with a ComboBox that does not display the SelectedItem when the popup control is loaded.  I am using MVVM, so there is no code behind except Initialization.  I am fairly new to programming, so I hope that I'm missing something easy.  However, I have other ComboBoxes that work fine with the same set-up I have on these so I am perpelxed.  I'm wondering if there may be something different about the Popup control, or using multiple View Models that I need to consider.

My markup code for the ComboBox inside the Popup user control is as follows:

```
             <ComboBox Name="comboBox1"
              Height="23"
              Margin="5,280,0,0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              IsEnabled="{Binding PaymentScheduleBaseUnitEnabled}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ScheduleBaseUnitList,
                                    Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice,
                                     Mode=TwoWay}"
              Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxShort}" />
```

Here is the code from my View Model with the bound properties.

```
 public ObservableCollection<ScheduleBaseUnit> ScheduleBaseUnitList
    {
        get
        {
            _scheduleBaseUnitList = _utilityRepository.GetScheduleBaseUnitList();

            return _scheduleBaseUnitList;
        }
        set
        {
            _scheduleBaseUnitList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ScheduleBaseUnitList");

        }
    }
```

And the SelectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice Property.

```
  public ScheduleBaseUnit SelectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice
    {
        get
        {
             if (_selectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice != null)
            {
                return
                    _scheduleBaseUnitList.FirstOrDefault(
                        c => c.ScheduleBaseUnitId == _selectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice.ScheduleBaseUnitId);
            }

        }
        set
        {
            if (_paymentFrequencyCustomer != null)
            {
                _paymentFrequencyCustomer.ScheduleBaseUnit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice");
                OnPropertyChanged("TestTwo");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the ScheduleBaseUnit Class

```
public class ScheduleBaseUnit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ScheduleBaseUnitId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ScheduleBaseUnit(int ScheduleBaseUnitId, string Description)
    {
        this.ScheduleBaseUnitId = ScheduleBaseUnitId;
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    public ScheduleBaseUnit()
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Description;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(ScheduleBaseUnit sbUnit)
    {
        if (sbUnit == null)
            return false;
        //return true if the fields match
        return sbUnit.ScheduleBaseUnitId == this.ScheduleBaseUnitId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The properties will bind just fine to a textbox, but not to a ComboBox.  I am truly perplexed on this one.  Thanks very much for the assistance everyone.

Comment: Have you check for any binding error in output window?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I checked the output window and there are no binding errors on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that you're not actually calling your strongly-type Equals method from your Equals override:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return this.Equals(obj as ScheduleBaseUnit);
}
```

As a best practice you should also add a more useful override to GetHashCode, ex:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.ScheduleBaseUnitId.GetHashCode();
}
```

If neither of these works, are you sure the selected item is in the ItemsSource collection?

Comment: Thanks tencntraze, I've made both of these changes. You were correct that my Equals method was not being called which was certainly one of the problems.  It is apparently not my only problem though, since the binding still is not working.

Comment: @MoZahid is also correct in that you need to look more closely at the SelectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChocie, since it's hard to follow what it's trying to do and the get/set don't really match each other.  Another possibility is that you're setting the ScheduleBaseUnitList property after setting the SelectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice, so the selection isn't getting picked up because there's no matching item in the ItemsSource

Comment: thank you very much.  I had to override the Equals, change the Property, and ensure my Mediator class was passing through the value between the viewmodels.  In an effort to be concise, I did not put the mediator code in my question... bad choice as it turns out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your not setting _selectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice anywhere. Also in the setter for SelectedBaseUnitPaymentFrequencyChoice Your checking if paymentFrequencyCustomer is not null and if it is null then the property changed won't be raised. You need to give this property abit more thought.

Comment: Could you consider formatting your code with some indents pls.